# logarithmic confusion

Tags: logarithms, exponential-function

I need to find the inverse function of the below equation.

$f(x) = \frac{e^x - e^{-x}}{e^x  + e^{-x}}$

When I apply ln to both sides I get the wrong answer.  I get the result of ylne - (-y)lne - (ylne-ylne) = 2y

lnx = 2y .

Why does this not work?

The way the solution is shown is by starting multiplying e^x to both the numerator and denominator which ends up giving a completely different answer.

Comment: You seem to be under the impression that $ln(e^x- e^{-x})= ln(e^x)- ln(e^{-x})$.  That is not true!  ln(a+ b) is NOT ln(a)+ ln(b).  (In fact that's true only for linear functions.  And very few functions are linear!)

Comment: thanks for clarifying

Comment: I reformatted your formula.  I hope that I interpreted it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it with hyperbolic functions.  See [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_function).

$\sinh x = \frac{e^x - e^{-x}}{2}$

$\cosh x = \frac{e^x + e^{-x}}{2}$

So, your expression is $\tanh x$ and its inverse is $\tanh^{-1} x$.

Comment: we answered almost contemporarily: I am going to cancel my answer, and +1!

Comment: Thanks.  You could have retained your answer and let the OP pick.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$y=f(x) = \frac{e^x - e^{-x}}{e^x  + e^{-x}}= \sinh (x) / \cosh(x) = \tanh(x)$

and 
 $x = arctanh(y) =\frac{1}{2} \ln ((1+y)/(1-y))$

re. to [inverse hyperbolic f.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_hyperbolic_functions)

Answer (score 1):

$$y=\frac{e^{2x}-1}{e^{2x}+1}$$
$$\frac{y+1}{y-1}=\frac{e^{2x}}{-1}$$
Replace x with y and y with x.
$$e^{2y}=\frac{1+x}{1-x}$$
$$2y=ln(\frac{1+x}{1-x})$$
$$f^{-1}(x)=ln(\frac{1+x}{1-x})$$

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're doing this:

$$\ln( e^x + e^{-x}) = \ln( e^x )+ \ln(e^{-x})$$

but $\ln$ doesn't distribute across addition, so that would be incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

The idea of $\log(a + b) = \log (a) + \log(1 + \frac{b}{a})$ is to isolate $a$ from $b$. As you can see $a$ was somewhat isolated as $\log (a)$, but $a$ & $b$ are still coupled as a ratio. I thought this transform would be useful for approximation (bounding), summation, asymptotic analysis.

I came up with a similar transform with trigonometric functions, which some people thought was useful in Polar Coordinates. I don't know as I don't work in it.